# Change all href on page using Javascript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, href

i need to change all links on a page to open an extra window when clicked,
so

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com"></a>
```

would become

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.bar.com');
    window.open('http://www.foo.com');">
```

preserving the previous URL, and opening the new link, simultaneously.

The new link would remain constant.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  If the user is clicking a different url on the page why wouldn't you just simply grab the clicked item and and then open both windows?

Comment: i hope i never have to visit that site

Comment: Links like that are a serious pain. DO NOT REMOVE the href. if you want the javascript to override the href, then simply have it return false after doing the window open call. By changing the links like this, you're killing any chance of your content showing up in search engines, for one. They do NOT parse javascript blocks for links.

Comment: @Marc B  the idea is to open the link that the user intends to click and another one, pop-under advert style.

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. But by removing the href, you kill any chance of a javascript-deprived user from using your site. Leave the href, add the onclick stuff, and have the onclick return false to override the actual link.

Comment: @Marc B - taken your advice and used OriginalSyn's code. Thank you all for your help and nice comments, especially yours @knittl ;)

Comment: Josh: you're welcome. Look "graceful degradation" and "progressive enhancement" for stuff like this. Build something that the lowest common denominator can use, then add flashier stuff on top of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery it would be something like

`$('a').click(function() { window.open('...'); });`

Comment: thanks, so i could just include the latest jQuerey.js, then replace the ... you put there with the http://www.bar.com?

Comment: Yea that should be it. As long as you don't put return false or event.stopPropegation() in the function it should visit both the default link and the one you've attached to the onclick handler

Comment: Hi, that doesnt seem to be working, my code is as such: `<html>
<head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></SCRIPT>
<script language="JavaScript">$('a').click(function() { window.open('http://www.bbc.co.uk'); });</script>

</head>

<body>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Click to open Google</a></p>
</body>

</html>` can you help please?

Comment: try wrapping your code with a $(document).ready(function() { /* code goes here */ }); The way you have it there it's trying to perform actions on the DOM before it's been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(function(){
  $('a').attr('target','_blank');
});
```

This should do the trick.

I am using jQuery to set attribute "target" for every anchor tag on page, to "_blank".

Comment: turns out he wants to open *two* windows when a link is clicked.

Comment: @Brad hence the two windows opening in the new href.